# Switch to last window in GNU Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I know how to list out the available windows in Screen using `C-a "` and/or `C-a '`, but how do you specify that you want to go to the very last screen without having to explicitly say so.

Like what I'm looking for is something like this:

`C-a L`

**NOTE**: I'm just asking whether screen supports this natively or if I'll have to write a bit of script in order to get this to work, also, tips and pointers for writing said script, if proved necessary, would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but it was wrong. I've fixed it. (It's C-a backspace, not C-a -)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a window 0 (i.e., you haven't closed it), you can do

```
C-a 0
```

(`select 0`) followed by

```
C-a <backspace>
```

(`prev`), which switches to the *previous* window; if you're on the first window, it wraps around to the last.

The `prev` command has several other default key bindings:

```
C-a h
C-a p
C-a C-p
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new windows with `Ctrl+a c` screen switches to the newly created last window. (If that isn't what you were looking for then:

```
screen -Q select $(screen -S $STY -Q windows|sed 's/ \([[:digit:]]*-*\**\)\$/\n\1/g'|tail -n1|cut -d: -f1|sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g')
```

will "Switch to last window in GNU Screen" from within any screen window.)

Alternatively (without depending on $STY, and presuming that you want the first or only screen session in `screen -ls`) you can use:

```
screen -S $(screen -ls|grep '^\s'|awk '{print $1}'|head -n1) -Q select $(screen -Q windows|sed 's/\([[:digit:]]*-*\**\)\$*\!*/\n\1/g'|grep '[[:digit:]]'|tail -n1|sed 's/[^[:digit:]]//g')
```

If this is something that you often need you can add:

```
_stslw_fn(){ screen -Q select $(screen -Q windows|sed 's/\([[:digit:]]*\)[^ ]*/\n\1/g'|tail -n1);};alias stslw="_stslw_fn"
```

to the end of `~/.bash_aliases` to create the `stslw` (switch to screen's last window) command.

Comment: `screen -Q select $(screen -Q windows|sed 's/\([[:digit:]]*\)[^ ]*/\n\1/g'|tail -n1)` is shorter